# Why GWT editor framework doesn't support arrays as args?

Tags: arrays, gwt

Let's assume that you want to create editor which implements interface `LeafValueEditor<int[]>` something like this:

```
class MyEditor implements LeafValueEditor<int[]> {
    @Override
    public void setValue(@NotNull int[] value) {

    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public int[] getValue() {
        return new int[0];
    }
}
```

If you are still using GWT 2.4 than above code will fail at runtime with NPE

```
Generator 'com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.SimpleBeanEditorDriverGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'HERE IS YOUR DRIVER CLASS' java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.model.EditorModel.findBeanPropertyMethods(EditorModel.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.model.EditorModel.createEditorData(EditorModel.java:407)
at com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.model.EditorModel.calculateEditorData(EditorModel.java:345)
at com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.model.EditorModel.<init>(EditorModel.java:237)
```

In GWT 2.5 the situation is a bit better. Editor framework will just ignore editors with such array-args in your driver description. Why does GWT-team decide to ignore the problem instead of solving it at this release?

I've looked through the source code of `EditorModel` and it doesn't look really hard to implement JArrayType support in that case. But it's really annoying problem cause I need to write boilerplate classes for wrapping arrays or to use java collections.

Comment: Have you filed a bug (or checked for an existing bug) ?

Comment: Actually I didn't find similar bugs. But I am not sure is there any explanation why this feature still is not implemented. May be it's not a bug.